# Easymock mocks object method invocation with another method invocation as an argument

Tags: java, testing, easymock

How to properly record mocks method when as an argument I put a result of another method of the same mock:

```
mockObj.doSth(arg1, arg2, mockObj.doSthElse(), arg2);
```

I'm testing a class method with class field as a mock (documentHelper):

```
  OperationInfo operationInfo = documentHelper.validate(document, documentHelper.getValidationDate(opData, document, true), lang, false);
```

Now my method test looks like this:

```
 @Test
    public void getOperationData_CheckClass() {

        //record
        this.recordGetDocument();

        DateTime dateTime = documentHelper.getValidationDate(operationData, document, true);
        expectLastCall().andReturn(new DateTime()).times(1);

        documentHelper.validate(document, dateTime, operation.getCustomPrincipal().getLang(), false);
        expectLastCall().andReturn(new OperationInfo()).times(1);

        //replay
        replay(documentHelper);

        //call
        OperationData opdata = operation.getOperationData(id, operationCode, null);
        Assert.assertEquals(operationData.getClass().getName(), opdata.getClass().getName());

        //verify
        verify(documentHelper);
    }
```

And getting error like:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call getValidationDate(...
```

on operation.getOperationData method invoked

Comment: What's the stack trace for the assertion error? And are you sure that the arguments to `getValidationDate` are the same ones your real code will be passing?

Comment: It seems like the document supposed to be taken from a different place ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think of it as:

```
int tmp = mockObj.doSthElse();
mockObj.doSth(arg1, arg2, tmp, arg3);
```

So you set up the expectation (and return value) for `doSthElse`, then you expect that value as the argument for `doSth`.

I can't explain why you're getting an unexpected method call for `getValidationDate()`, but the `dateTime` value you're passing into the `validate` mock is incorrect - you should be using:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
documentHelper.getValidationDate(operationData, document, true).andReturn(dateTime);
```

Comment: typo corrected :), please see my edit to check what's can be wrong there